# Android + Firebase, getValue from database and populate viewText field

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So... thanks to some great assistance from TomiQsrd I have got my data being saved in Firebase as below:

```
    private void saveUserInformation(){
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Name").setValue(name);
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Address").setValue(address);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The rest of my project is pretty much completed, but I have one last part I can't figure out no matter how many tutorials I watch/read.

How on earth do I get an event listener to pick up changes in the data and update a `TextView` field.

eg. As a test, I want to add a textViewName field to the page to update when the name is updated in editTextName

I have tried all sorts of approaches and must have been close, but I have not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Modified from there:

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String name = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
      myTextView.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```